# Proving that the following sequence is Cauchy

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Consider the sequence ${a_n}$ that is produced by flipping a coin. Begin by flipping the coin and setting $a_1=1$ if it lands on heads and $a_2=-1$ if it lands on tails. Flipping the coin again and setting $a_2=a_1+\frac{1}{2}$ for heads and $a_2=a_1-\frac{1}{2}$ for tails. If I do this $n$ times I get,
$$
a_{n+1} = \left\{\begin{aligned}
&a_n + \frac{1}{2^n}&&:  \text{if heads}\\
&a_n-\frac{1}{2^n}&&: \text{if  tails}
\end{aligned}
\right.$$

Values of $a_n$ depend on random flips. How can I prove that ${a_n}$ is a Cauchy sequence? Any solutions or hints welcome.

Comment: As a hint, it's very relevant that $$\sum_{n = N}^{\infty} \pm \frac 1 {2^n}$$ tends to $0$ as $N$ grows, regardless of the choice of signs; try comparing with a geometric series after applying the triangle inequality.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the definition entails $$\sum_{n\geqslant 1}|a_{n+1}-a_n|<+\infty$$ Since the sequence is of bounded variation it is Cauchy. Can you prove that?